# How to handle duplicate TDictionary <string, Integer> error

Tags: delphi, pascal, tdictionary

how to handle the error of duplicate value in the list. Values are fed into the input and entered into the list. If there is a duplicate then the value is renamed.
eg:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 CollectionNameTable : TDictionary<string, Integer>;
begin
  CollectionNameTable := TDictionary<string, Integer>.Create();
   try
     CollectionNameTable.Add('One', 1);
     CollectionNameTable.Add('TWO', 2);
     CollectionNameTable.Add('TWO', 3);
     CollectionNameTable.Add('FOUR', 4);
      except on E: EStringListError do
       begin
          ShowMessage( 'Дубликат!!!');
          CollectionNameTable.Add('DOUBLE_FREE', 3);
       end;

   end;

    CollectionNameTable.Clear;
    CollectionNameTable.Free;

end;
```

Comment: Call `ContainsKey` before attempting to add, and handle the error at that point. You should not wait for an exception to be raised. A better dictionary class (e.g. spring4d) offers the `TryAdd` pattern which is more efficient.

Comment: Are you looking for [`AddOrSetValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary.AddOrSetValue)?

Comment: no, when a value is duplicated, I need to rename it so that there are no identical values

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't quite obvious to me (since the `e.g.` part didn't do or indicate any renaming). Well, then you need to use `ContainsKey` as David suggested.

Comment: Personally I'd use the spring4d dictionary. It grinds my gears that you would do two hash lookups when one suffices, because of the limited design of the RTL class.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That annoys me too. But personally I try to avoid third-party code if possible. The OP has to decide for themself.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I did it through ContainsKey, I ruled out mistakes, and in the direction of the spring4d dictionary - you need to figure out how to use it and it might really be more rational.

Comment: @Andreas You use the RTL and VCL all the time.....